# Export to CSV does not datetime properly

Tags: highcharts

I'm trying to export a chart data to csv using highcharts. X-Axis is datetime and Y-Axis is a combination of two datas. Y-Axis data shows up properly with the title specified. But for X-Axis, exported data shows up as category and 1/1/1970 as default value for all the entries.

I have tried different solutions mentioned in highchart documentation but nothing changed.

```
title: {
    text: ' '
},
subtitle: {
     text: ' '
},
xAxis: {
     type: 'datetime',
     title: {
           text: 'TLY Year'
     }
},
yAxis: [{
     labels: {
             format: '{value} kW',
              style: {
                     color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
      },
      title: {
              text: 'kW',
              style: {
                    color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]
              }
      }
 }]
```

```
Category
1/1/1970
```

Sample Data:
[image]

Comment: What does your data look like? Could you include a sample of your data?

Comment: @ewolden: I updated my post with sample data

Comment: Could you reproduce this issue in an online code editor like jsfiddle?